# Finding the format being used on Apache log

Tags: apache, http, logging

I am attempting to perform some data analysis on a set of Apache access logs that were passed on to me, but I noticed these logs do not seem to be in a conventional format (based on a few other Apache log examples I found online). Following is one row extracted from one of my log files (after some anonymization):

```
2013-08-25 10:06:11 EDT - "GET http://www.siteaddress.com/section/aaa/z/directory HTTP/1.1" 404 1677 1.2.181.171 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows 98)" - 0 155311 -
```

Is there any way I can find out what format is being used to record these logs? That is, how would I go about getting some sort of a header for this file? Ps.: I have access to the server that is capturing these logs and could use it to find that information out.

**Edit 1:** I was told to check the content of */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*, which I found to be empty.

**Edit 2:** The following relevant piece was found within *apache2.conf* but I'm not quite sure these match what I'm seeing in the logs.

```
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""  vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

**Edit 3:** Found this within */etc/apache2/sites-available/hub* and it seems to match my format (Thanks a lot!)

```
LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z}t %u \"%r\" %>s %B %a \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" - %T %D -"
```

Comment: What System/Distribution are you on? Debian-based?

Comment: Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.10 (lenny)
Release:        5.0.10
Codename:       lenny

Comment: None of those `LogFormat` directives match the log format you're seeing; you'll probably want to go hunting for `CustomLog` directives, per my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debian based distros, the config is split into multiple files. Main configuration is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, while all vHosts (that are used by default) are configured in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (they might not be active though, when activating virtual hosts using `a2ensite` a symlink in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ is created, from where the files get included)

If you have never messed with the config, the log format should either be set in
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` inside the `VirtualHost` container ot in apache2.conf

Answer (score 1):

You can find the format specification in one of the Apache configuration files; depending on your server configuration, that may be the primary config file (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, probably; that's the default on Debian and its derivates, while `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` is common among the Rat Head family), or in the configuration file for the virtual host whose logs you're looking at (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*` for Debian and company, God only knows where for Rat Head).

The configuration directive you're after will be either `LogFormat`, which aliases a format string to a short name, or `CustomLog`, which uses either a format string, or a short name defined earlier in a `LogFormat` directive, to specify an actual logging format.

The format string syntax is detailed [in the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html).

To save you some time, from eyeballing the sample line and having had considerable experience of Apache logs, most of the format appears to be:

```
<datetime> - "<request method> <url> <HTTP version>" <response status> <response length> <client address> "<request Referer: header value?>" "<request User-Agent: header value>" - ?? <response duration in microseconds?> - <newline>
```

I don't know offhand what the parts involving question marks are, but the rest seem pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was spot on, but @Johannes H. beat you by 10 seconds